# why can't I give separate declaration and defintion of a variable in global scope in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int temp;
int b=2;
temp = b;
int main(){
  cout<<"temp is "<<temp<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here I am just assigning value of b to temp and gcc does not allow me to do that but if I move line "temp=b" in main scope it works fine. I don't understand this behavior. can anybody explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = b;
```

is *not* a definition, it's an *assignment.*

Assignments can only be done in certain places such as within a function or block.

There *are* actually ways to get variables set distinctly from their declaration outside of `main` and its children, but they have problems of their own (google for `static initialisation order fiasco` for example). It's probably best to do it after `main` starts so you can control the order in which things are done.

Answer (score 0):

`temp = b` is assignation and must be done in a code block (inside a function).